# integrating eclipse (not EE) with tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse indigo and I want to integrate it with pre-installed tomcat7 server I have.
I know how to do it easily in java EE, but now I need to run it not on EE.
Is it possible? If so, how?
Many thanks for  anyone who can help.

Comment: Install the web tools platform plugin, or doanload a version of eclipse that has the WTP pre-bundled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, no, not without the plug-ins you already have or alternates that essentially do the same thing.  I don't understand the "I need to run it not on EE" part, though.  Why?